# rails active record time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been working with one rails project, when the creation of object , i need exact time with created_at field.I have tried these in applicaiton.rb

```
config.time_zone = 'Chennai'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

and when i tried in console, it shows like

```
Time.now
=> 2014-08-28 21:31:31 +0530
m.created_at
=> Thu, 28 Aug 2014 21:28:26 IST +05:30
```

but the problem is when i take one database object, the created_at time is

```
 created_at: "2014-08-28 15:58:26"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails stores all timestamps in `UTC` in the database. When you type those commands on console it converts the timestamp to your specific timezone.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html

I your particular case `2014-08-28 15:58:26 UTC` is same as `2014-08-28 21:28:26 IST`.

Saving all timestamps as UTC makes the data consistent, and has less scope for ambiguity. You can then do all the conversions based on the timezone of your choice.